# Get ASP.NET WebForms ComboBox element when JQuery autocompleteselect is fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms, jquery-ui-autocomplete

How can I get the underlying `select` element when JQuery `autocompleteselect` is fired? I need that element to fire its `onchange()`. The underlying `select` element is an ASP.NET DropDown control. Here's the code:

```
this._on(this.input, {
        autocompleteselect: function (event, ui) {
               var ele = this; //<---not working
               ui.item.option.selected = true;
               this._trigger("select", event, {
               item: ui.item.option
             });
        },

        autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured it out:

```
autocompleteselect: function (event, ui) {

      ui.item.option.selected = true;
      this._trigger("select", event, {
                         item: ui.item.option
                   });

      var underlyingEle = document.getElementById(
      ui.item.option.parentElement.id // <-- fetching the underlying select element
      ); 
      underlyingEle.onchange();
}
```

Hope this helps someone in future. :)